# Servlet response wrapper has encoding problem

Tags: java, servlets, character-encoding, wrapper, servlet-filters

A servlet response wrapper is being used in a Servlet Filter. The idea is that the response is manipulated, with a 'nonce' value being injected into forms, as part of defence against CSRF attacks.

The web app is using UTF-8 everywhere. When the Servlet Filter is absent, no problems. When the filter is added, encoding issues occur. (It seems as if the response is reverting to 8859-1.)

The guts of the code :

```
final class CsrfResponseWrapper extends AbstractResponseWrapper {
   ...
   byte[] modifyResponse(byte[] aInputResponse){
      ...
      String originalInput = new String(aInputResponse, encoding);
      String modifiedResult = addHiddenParamToPostedForms(originalInput);
      result = modifiedResult.getBytes(encoding);
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

As I understand it, the transition between byte-land and String-land should specify an encoding. That is done here, as you can see, in two places. The value of the 'encoding' variable is 'UTF-8'; the alteration of the String itself is standard string manipulation (with a regex), and never specifies an encoding (addHiddenParamToPostedForms).

Where am I in error about the encoding?

EDIT:
Here is the base class (sorry it's rather long):

```
package hirondelle.web4j.security;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

/**
 Abstract Base Class for altering response content.
 (May be useful in future contexts as well. For now, keep package-private.)  
*/
abstract class AbstractResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

  AbstractResponseWrapper(ServletResponse aServletResponse) throws IOException {
    super((HttpServletResponse)aServletResponse);
    fOutputStream = new ModifiedOutputStream(aServletResponse.getOutputStream());
    fWriter = new PrintWriter(fOutputStream);
  }

  /** Return the modified response. */
  abstract byte[] modifyResponse(byte[] aInputResponse);

  /** Standard servlet method.  */
  public final ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() {
    //fLogger.fine("Modified Response : Getting output stream.");
    if ( fWriterReturned ) {
      throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    fOutputStreamReturned = true;
    return fOutputStream;
  }

  /** Standard servlet method.  */
  public final PrintWriter getWriter() {
    //fLogger.fine("Modified Response : Getting writer.");
    if ( fOutputStreamReturned ) {
      throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    fWriterReturned = true;
    return fWriter;
  }

  // PRIVATE

  /*
   Well-behaved servlets return either an OutputStream or a PrintWriter, but not both.
  */
  private PrintWriter fWriter; 
  private ModifiedOutputStream fOutputStream;

  /*
   These items are used to implement conformance to the 
   javadoc for ServletResponse, regarding exceptions being thrown.
  */
  private boolean fWriterReturned;
  private boolean fOutputStreamReturned;

  /** Modified low level output stream.  */
  private class ModifiedOutputStream extends ServletOutputStream {
    public ModifiedOutputStream(ServletOutputStream aOutputStream) {
      fServletOutputStream = aOutputStream;
      fBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    }
    /** Must be implemented to make this class concrete.   */
    public void write(int aByte) {
      fBuffer.write(aByte);
    }
    public void close() throws IOException {
      if ( !fIsClosed ){
        processStream();
        fServletOutputStream.close();
        fIsClosed = true;
      }
    }
    public void flush() throws IOException {
      if ( fBuffer.size() != 0 ){
        if ( !fIsClosed ) {
          processStream(); 
          fBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        }
      }
    }
    /** Perform the core processing, by calling the abstract method.  */
    public void processStream() throws IOException {
      fServletOutputStream.write(modifyResponse(fBuffer.toByteArray()));
      fServletOutputStream.flush();
    }
    // PRIVATE //
    private ServletOutputStream fServletOutputStream;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream fBuffer;
    /** Tracks if this stream has been closed.    */
    private boolean fIsClosed = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [`new PrintWriter(OutputStream)` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.OutputStream%29):

> Creates a new PrintWriter, without automatic line flushing, from an existing OutputStream. This convenience constructor creates the necessary intermediate OutputStreamWriter, which will convert characters into bytes **using the default character encoding**.

There's your culprit. Have a look at [`OutputStreamWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) where you can specify the encoding.

Comment: Yes, this fixes the issue. I modified and simplified the code, after the style in this tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html

Answer (score 0):

The code you present does not not seem to be in error.

What are you doing elsewhere?

- are there other filters in the chain that may manipulate the encoding/byte stream, maybe you have a filter position problem
- is "encoding" fix or dynamically read from the request?

Comment: There are 2 other filters in the chain: one suppresses extraneous sessions, the other performs tasks linked to user login. Neither alters the response stream. The 'encoding' item is fixed.

Comment: There's nothing obvious. You are sure, the communication is on UTF-8 if this one is not in place? Does your wrapper correctly forward the encoding setting?

Comment: Pretty sure, yes. Firefox shows UTF-8 in the response header; my JSP's are all saved in UTF-8. I seem to get '?' chars in the output wherever I reference a tag file. And, when the offending filter's absent, I can see Arabic chars fine.

Comment: FYI - The base class is the likely suspect.